# Dynamic amp-story

Tags: amp-list, amp-mustache, amp-stories

i try to figure out, how i can build dynamic amp-stories.
Assume i have a website like this: `https://example.com/stories/:slug`. This page should fetch the data for a story (with this slug) from my server first (it outputs some json data) and then it should render the data as a amp-story.

My first attempt is to use the story inside an amp-list / amp-mustache template (i removed all attributes to have a smaller example):

```html
...
<body>
  <amp-list>
    <template type="amp-mustache">
      <amp-story standalone>
        {{#items}}
          <amp-story-page id="{{id}}">
            ...
          </amp-story-page>
        {{/items}}
      </amp-story>
    </template>
  </amp-list>
</body>
...
```

Now, i get this validation error:

> The parent tag of tag 'amp-story' is 'template', but it can only be
>   'body'.

So this isn't allowed... If i switch the order of some elements like this:

```html
<body>
  <amp-story standalone>
    <amp-list>
      <template type="amp-mustache">
        {{#items}}
          <amp-story-page id="{{id}}">
            ...
          </amp-story-page>
        {{/items}}
    </template>
  </amp-story>
</body>
```

the validator claims for pages:

> Story must have at least one page.

So this isn't allowed as well.

Well, is it even possible to construct a story like this or do i have to use the server to create my story pages?

Comment: Can you try validating the HTML output rather than the templating logic itself? This is what matters to crawlers and search engines in the end. :)
That means you would need some Server Side Rendering to publish your stories. Some frameworks support this out of the box, like nextjs with React (cf: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/amp-support/introduction)

Comment: This tutorial may prove of some use to you, especially the chapter titled: "Creating the Cover Page" https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/start/visual_story/setting_up/?format=websites

Comment: Well, thanks. We decided to use a serverside rendering framework to generate the stories. @Gmajoulet: The output is valid html, but AMP isn't "normal" html so i was trying to make the AMP-validator happy.